# Can backups of root mounted to a logical volume be restored to a larger logical volume?

Tags: backup, dd, lvm, restore

My current Ubuntu setup has root mounted to a LVM2 logical volume 'lvroot'. lvroot is 10G. I've been taking snapshots of lvroot, and then making dd backups of the snapshots (which creates a backup of lvroot as it existed at time snapshot was made), so those backups are 10G.

If I enlarge lvroot to 15G (lvextend and resize2fs), can I restore (via dd) the 10G backup to the now-larger lvroot? Would I need to run resize2fs immediately after the restore?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

After restoring your dd image to the new larger LV you would need to "fsck -f" (to force a check on the resulting image, and ensure it is marked clean) and then "resize2fs" the LV in order for the restored image to expand and see the new space.